# Draw dynamic horizontal line based on selected bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to draw a dynamic horizontal line `(Close + ATR(10))` based on the bar selected by the cursor.

Currently, I use plot() but it looks messy.

I am using pinescript v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an option that is to some extent a compromise.

```
bar_time = input.time(1673257327000, "Bar time")
if time == bar_time
    // your dynamic logic determining "y"
    line.new(bar_index, y, bar_index, y, extend = extend.both)
```

The `input.time()` gives you a draggable vertical line in the chart GUI over the bar defined by the time input that you can move to your desired bar that sets your horizontal line based on your logic. This vertical line is only a helper utility from tradingview to be able to control input.time() rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript v5 you can't get information from the GUI.